Why is a native TypeScript enum's built-in reverse mapping not recognized at compile-time?
I have a generic function which takes a native TypeScript enum and a mapping from that enum's values to strings.
Native TypeScript enums have such mappings built-in:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings
But when I pass the native TypeScript enum as the mapping, it fails to compile, with an error that it's missing keys for the values. Why is that?
Runnable TypeScript Playground link, but code here too for convenience:
// Let's say I have a native TypeScript enum with numeric values, like this.
// (From https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-node/blob/v1.4.0/models/AutoRenewStatus.ts)
enum AutoRenewStatus {
  OFF = 0,
  ON = 1
}

// And I'm calling a generic function that accepts any kind of enum.
// This is the generic type for that use case that Zod uses:
// https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/v3.23.8/src/types.ts#L4294
type EnumLike = {
  [k: string]: string | number;
  [nu: number]: string;
};

// Here's my generic function. The internal implementation is omitted here.
// It takes the native enum, and a mapping from the native enum's values to strings.
declare function transformNumericNativeEnumToString<
  Input extends EnumLike,
  Output extends string,
  Mappings extends Record<Input[keyof Input], Output>,
>(values: Input, mappings: Mappings): unknown;

// This compiles, but is boilerplate-y:
transformNumericNativeEnumToString(AutoRenewStatus, {
  [AutoRenewStatus.OFF]: 'OFF',
  [AutoRenewStatus.ON]: 'ON',
});

// Why does this not? Fails with error:
//
// > Type 'typeof AutoRenewStatus' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<AutoRenewStatus, string>': 0, 1
//
// But native TypeScript enums do have reverse mappings from values back to names:
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings
transformNumericNativeEnumToString(AutoRenewStatus, AutoRenewStatus);



TS doesn't strongly type reverse enums, see ms/TS#38806. But your example code is problematic for demonstrating that; transformNumericNativeEnumToString has no inference site for Output, so Mappings will always be Record<Input[keyof Input], string>, but for a numeric enum Input[keyof Input] will include string, but... a numeric enum is not assignable to Record<string, string> so of course that would fail.  If you had strong reverse mappings your problem would be worse. Please [edit] to resolve this.
